# Python frequency of words using gensim: How to get the word instead of id word in corpus

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim

I use gensim  to count the frequency of words in a given note.

After applying the following code:

```
from gensim import corpora
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(sentences) 
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in sentences]
```

Obtains a corpus such as:
[(0, 1), (1, 5), (3, 1) ...]

I would like corpus such as:
[(word_1, 1), (word_2, 5), (word_3, 1) ...]

So I want to get the word instead of id  word in corpus.

Can someone help me how I can get this and then save such a corpus as an excel file?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_corpora_and_vector_spaces.html) the word mapping can be found in `dictionary.token2id`. For quick lookup let's inverse the key-value mappings of `dictionary.token2id` and apply list comprehension:

```
mapping = {v: k for k, v in dictionary.token2id.items()}
[(mapping[i[0]], i[1]) for i in corpus]
```

But as you're using list comprehension in your sample data, `corpus` will likely contain a list of lists. In that case you could use:

```
[[(mapping[i[0]], i[1]) for i in item] for item in corpus]
```